# Height of parent div is zero with finite height child divs in safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, angular-material

Though I have tried using clear fix but that didn't solved the purpose

code looks like

```
<div>
<div flex="25">
    <md-card>
    </md-card>
</div>
<div flex="25">
    <md-card>
    </md-card>
</div>
<div flex="50">
    <md-card>
    </md-card>
</div>
```

Now all the three internal divs are taking height 0 px in safari but working fine according to the angular material flex technique in chrome and safari.